# Images of a particular website aren't loaded

Tags: images, website

The website is : http://www.ntvmsnbc.com

- Images aren't loaded for this website.
- I tried with the browsers -> IE9, Firefox 4, Chrome.
- I use no proxy, no dns, no ad-block services.
- I closed firewalls.
- I disabled Kaspersky Antivirus.
- I tried with different DNSs.
- I don't have any problem with any other websites.
- I tried entering the website with tunnel websites (ktunnel etc.), and it seems to work fine.
- I have no addons installed, except Java, Flash Player which are all updated to the date.

So, what i am asking is what should I do to solve this problem?

---

Host Files is clean. The default host file. I am using Windows 7 64bit version.

Comment: What happens when you directly type the address into your browser ?

eg http://media1.ntvmsnbc.com/i/NTVMSNBC/Components/ArtAndPhoto-Fronts/SectionsThumbnails-TSM-Colorbox/_Cover/110609-anoymmm.jpg

Comment: The page can not be displayed.

Comment: Is your computers IP address in a private address range? Have you tried on different computers?

Answer (score 2):

Where are the images coming from? The same website or a separate images site?

I'd also try incognito mode on Chrome, it disables every add-on.

Did you check your hosts file? Many tools on Windows (you don't mention your OS) add adblock entries to the hosts file (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt).

Comment: host file is clean, i am using Win7-64bit

Comment: Incognito mode is tried also, no success.

Answer (score 0):

Given all the things you've tried all I can suggest is that your ISP has some kind of active filtering on the site media1.ntvmsnbc.com

By trying different browsers, disabling Kaspersky, checking the Hosts file and using different DNS settings you have pretty much ruled out anything on your machine.

The fact that it works when going through a tunneling service (you mention ktunnel) means that you are bypassing whatever transparent proxy your ISP might be using and therefore that is almost certainly where the problem lies.

Contact your ISP and explain the situation to them.  The level of detail in your post should give them a good idea where the problem is, it could be an overly aggressive spam/content filter or simply a cache needing clearing on their side.

The absolute last thing you can do on your side is to go to your network adaptor settings and do a repair as this should clear all your local network route caches.  Go to the The Network and Sharing Center, click  "Troubleshoot problems" at the bottom then try the "Internet Connections" and "Network Adaptor" troubleshooters.  If neither of these can find, fix or repair any problems then you will have to talk to your ISP.